# Binding a XamDataGrid with listcollectionview (to be refresh with some throttle)

Tags: wpf, .net-4.0, system.reactive, throttling, listcollectionview

I am binding a listcollectionview to xamdatagrid but I don't want default binding behavior ie Notify UI For each change in binded list.I just want my UI-grid to be updated after every 500 MS.How can I do it (**using Rx?**).Can some body please suggest a solution

PS: My project is on .net 4.0 so I can't use "delay" tag in binding.

Comment: This is a very dirty solution, but what you want to do is dirty, too - in my opinion. So: you could implement a command to some hidden element and check in the CanExecute method the time elapsed. After your period you refresh the grid.

Comment: challenge is how to stop auto updates due to binding due to which every changed in list notifies UI.

Comment: Since I have too many updates on my collection so UI gets freeze sometime.So I just want my list to be populated from sourcelist having some throttle.